# Nothing happens when I click on the Spinner item

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-spinner

I have fetched data from the server from the category class.The getcategories method return the List of String containing spinner items. When I click on the spinner item. Nothing happens. Is there any mistake in my code. Please help.

This is my java code.

```
public void fetchPropertyType(){
        category = new Category();   //Spinner Item model
        //categories is a array list of String which contains the items of spinner
        categories = category.getCategories(AddPropertyActivity.this);

        //Property Type Spinner Adapter
        propertyTypeSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.property_type_spinner);
        Log.e("Test", "Just a test message");

        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, categories);
        // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        // attaching data adapter to spinner
        propertyTypeSpinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

        propertyTypeSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(),
                        "OnItemSelectedListener : " + parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                Log.e("Test", "Nothing selected  on spinner activity");

            }
        });
    }
```

This is my layout

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/spinner_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Property Type"
        android:textAlignment="textEnd"/>

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/property_type_spinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Hi Xantosh Lamsal,you can check my answer.That I used it in my code was ok. You can have a try.

Answer (score 1):

You just should do this.

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/border">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/spinner_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Property Type"
        android:textAlignment="textEnd"/>

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/property_type_spinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**In the Spinner**

**Change**

```
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

**To**

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Because you use `android:layout_height="match_parent"`,so you can't see your list item.And nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using

```
 <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/property_type_spinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown"/>
```

Which wraps the height of spinner  so try to give custom height to it so that i t will be clickable

I did this

```
<Spinner
        android:id="@+id/property_type_spinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:spinnerMode="dropdown"/>
```

and keep your text view height wrap_content as

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/spinner_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Property Type"/>
```